# При клике по крестику только 1 модальное окно закрывается, остальные нет. Что не так?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, вёрстка, frontend

в HTML меняется только ID, что не так в JS вроде у каждого есть CLOSE, но работает только 1-й. Остальные же почему то закрываются только по клику за пределами окна, а по крестику не закрываются.

```js
     <script type="text/javascript">
     
var modalz = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var spa1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var spa2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
var spa2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];
var mod_cont1 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
var mod_cont2 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[1];
var mod_cont3 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[2];
var mod_cont4 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[3];
var mod_cont5 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[4];
var mod_cont6 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[5];
var mod_cont7 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[6];
var mod_cont8 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[7];
var mod_class = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
        modalz.style.display = "block";
}
spa1.onclick = function() {
    modalz.style.display = "none";
}

spa2.onclick = function() {
    two.style.display = "none";
}

mod_cont1.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
mod_cont2.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
mod_cont3.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
mod_cont4.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
mod_cont5.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
mod_cont6.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
mod_cont7.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
mod_cont8.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}

modalz.onclick = function(event){
    modalz.style.display = "none";
}

var two = document.getElementById('two');
var raz = document.getElementById("raz");
var spaned = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

two.onclick = function(e){
    this.style.display = 'none';
}

raz.onclick = function(e) {
    two.style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
}

var thereon = document.getElementById('thereon');
var there = document.getElementById("there");
var spaned = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

thereon.onclick = function(e){
    this.style.display = 'none';
}

there.onclick = function(e) {
    thereon.style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
}

var fooon = document.getElementById('fooon');
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var spaned = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

fooon.onclick = function(e){
    this.style.display = 'none';
}

foo.onclick = function(e) {
    fooon.style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
}

var fiveon = document.getElementById('fiveon');
var five = document.getElementById("five");
var spaned = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

fiveon.onclick = function(e){
    this.style.display = 'none';
}

five.onclick = function(e) {
    fiveon.style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
}

var sixeon = document.getElementById('sixon');
var six = document.getElementById("six");
var spaned = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

sixon.onclick = function(e){
    this.style.display = 'none';
}

six.onclick = function(e) {
    sixon.style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
}

var sevenon = document.getElementById('sevenon');
var seven = document.getElementById("seven");
var spaned = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

sevenon.onclick = function(e){
    this.style.display = 'none';
}

seven.onclick = function(e) {
    sevenon.style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
}

var eathon = document.getElementById('eathon');
var eath = document.getElementById("eath");
var spaned = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

eathon.onclick = function(e){
    this.style.display = 'none';
}

eath.onclick = function(e) {
    eathon.style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
}
 </script>
```

```html
<a id="myBtn">
div id="myModal" class="modal">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае нереально дать ответ по существу вопроса.
Попробуйте сначала занятся codestyle. 
Например, вереница

```
document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0]
```

Заменяется на что-то вроде:

```js
// your func was good too, but I love querySelector
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
[].forEach.call(modals, function(item) {
  console.log(item.innerHTML)
  // item.onclick = function() {}
});
```

```html
<div class='modal'>1</div>
<div class='modal'>2</div>
<div class='modal'>3</div>
<div class='modal'>4</div>
```

Так что, пожалуйста, приведите сначала в порядок код, а потом спрашивайте.

Comment: Вячеслав, спасибо за ответ, тогда такой вопрос, а если вы сможете наглядно увидеть это все на сайте, в таком случае есть возможность получить ответ на текущий вопрос?

Comment: Да, конечно. И переписать это нормально вдобавок

Answer (score 1):

```js
var modalz = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var spa1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var spa2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
var spa3 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];
var spa4 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[3];
var spa5 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[4];
var spa6 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[5];
var spa7 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[6];
var spa8 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[7];
var mod_cont1 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
var mod_cont2 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[1];
var mod_cont3 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[2];
var mod_cont4 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[3];
var mod_cont5 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[4];
var mod_cont6 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[5];
var mod_cont7 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[6];
var mod_cont8 = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[7];
var mod_class = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
        modalz.style.display = "block";
}
spa1.onclick = function() {
    modalz.style.display = "none";
}

spa2.onclick = function() {
    two.style.display = "none";
}
spa3.onclick = function() {
    thereon.style.display = "none";
}
spa4.onclick = function() {
    fooon.style.display = "none";
}
spa5.onclick = function() {
    fiveon.style.display = "none";
}
spa6.onclick = function() {
    sixon.style.display = "none";
}
spa7.onclick = function() {
    sevenon.style.display = "none";
}
spa8.onclick = function() {
    eathon.style.display = "none";
```

вот решение